# .htaccess mod-rewrite how to fetch a non-word character

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess file, `\w` matches a word, i.e., numbers or letters. But it does not matches special characters like `-`. So, what escape character matches these characters ?

Comment: What do you want to match (i mean, each characters in entire string) ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I want to match a string like "an-example-string-123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `-` with word character `\w` you will need to use character class:

```
[\w-]
```

Comment: I used (\w+) to match for words i.e. a-zA-Z0-9_ and it matched successfully. But using (\w-) there was a 404

Comment: You need to use `([\w-]+)` for that